# why such behavior in Linux Network over Loopback Interface

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, linux-kernel, network-interface

I have one physical interface Ethernet with name **eth0** and IP address **192.168.40.50** and a **lo**(loopback) with **127.0.0.1**. After manually down lo using `ifconfig lo down` command, then I observed that  self ping on Ethernet (**192.168.40.50**) has been stopped. What is the specific reason for this type of behavior in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `lo` is called the loopback interface. Any communication with-in the local environment (your computer) is carried over this interface, i.e, routed through this interface. So in your case, when you are trying to ping your own physical interface, your linux box will try to route the ICMP traffic through `lo` which is down. So the packets will never reach your interface to send ECHO-reply.